# storm-starter example topologies crash

Tags: apache-storm, distributed-computing

I am just getting started with the Twitter Storm framework on OS X 10.9.5. However, I am running into a problem with running the example topologies in storm-starter: https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter.

Following the readme, I try to deploy a topology locally by calling

```
sudo mvn exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

The topology runs for less than a minute, and then terminates in an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project storm-starter: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project storm-starter: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at backtype.storm.util$wrap_in_runtime.invoke(util.clj:44)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_$fn__907.invoke(zookeeper.clj:102)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_.invoke(zookeep`enter code here`er.clj:98)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$mkdirs.invoke(zookeeper.clj:114)
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_distributed_cluster_state$reify__1757.mkdirs(cluster.clj:119)
    at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2214.report_error(cluster.clj:397)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$throttled_report_error_fn$fn__3547.invoke(executor.clj:179)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3767$fn$reify__3812.reportError(executor.clj:737)
    at backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector.reportError(OutputCollector.java:223)
    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.die(ShellBolt.java:303)
    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.access$800(ShellBolt.java:68)
    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt$1.run(ShellBolt.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.submitRequest(ClientCnxn.java:1342)
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1040)
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:161)
    at org.apache.storm.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.storm.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:36)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$exists_node_QMARK_$fn__907.invoke(zookeeper.clj:101)
    ... 11 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you need `sudo`?

Comment: Hello! This issue is filed on Apache Storm's JIRA page [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-531). No progress @ time of comment.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the issue you are seeing is the result of the cluster shutdown:

See [./src/jvm/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java]:

```
...
else {
  conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);

  LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
  cluster.submitTopology("word-count", conf, builder.createTopology());

  Thread.sleep(10000); //<----- HERE

  cluster.shutdown();  //<----- HERE
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Storm 0.9.3 multi-lang is not backward-compatible, and the `WordCountTopology.java` example in storm-starter has not been updated for the changes.

> In addition to the Node.js implementation, the multi-lang protocol has been substantially improved in terms of robustness and error handling capabilities. As a result, **the multi-lang API has changed in a non-backward-compatible way**. Users with existing multi-lang topologies should consult the Python, Ruby, and JavaScript multi-lang examples to determine the impact prior to upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I don't have a complete fix yet, but the error stems from python.
If you take a look at the WordCountTopology class you see the following constructor of the inner class SplitSentence:

```
public SplitSentence() {
  super("python", "splitsentence.py");
}
```

And if you replace this with a Java code, namely give this class an execute() method, where the String-splits are made, everything works fine.

So something with the python does not work out, although the python code works and splits the Strings. Hope this helped at least a little!

Answer (score 1):

As @booleys1012 noted this is because when you run mvn exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology and not give any params to submit to a cluster it runs in a LocalCluster( a simulated storm cluster for testing out topologies). This will for 10 seconds and calls cluster.shutdown() which causes it throw InterruptedException as you are seeing the error. This is expected its not an issue with storm.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late for this question, I guess, but I am just getting started with Apache Storm on macOS Sierra too and discovered that this error occurred while installing newer versions. Finally, I followed the directions at this link I found:

http://www.haroldnguyen.com/blog/category/storm/

So, I installed the 0.9.2 version and everything worked like a charm!

ps. I also tried it on Ubuntu 16.04 and worked great, too.